# How to notify Google about expired content?

Tags: seo, google

We run a classified ad website.

When the users delete their ads, they want the indexed page removed instantly from Google.

We have seen 2 complementary strategies:

- Adding a `noarchive` (Craigslist is the only one doing it).
- Adding the deleted ads in the sitemap with the deletion date used as `<lastmod>`.

We have an decent number of pages crawled/indexed by Google (+15'000'000). So it is important that the added and deleted ads are handled in priority and promptly. Modified ads or categorie pages can be handled next.

How can we do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to assume that there is one page per ad at some point and that there are pages that categorize and list ads.

With that, do what I do, blank the page- sorta. When the ad is deleted, make the public facing page something obvious; "sold", "ad removed", etc. but you can make it a useful landing page too. For example, *more bicycles for sale* and list a few. From there, you can update the page with a mechanism that alerts Google not to index the page such as `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">` Otherwise, remove the page and tell Google that the page is gone with a 404 or 410 (preferred) error. Of course you can do both, take the first option for a while to capture and salvage valuable traffic then remove the page after a short period.

Noarchive is not the same as noindex. It just means do not create an archive copy. With noarchive, Google would still index the page, however, with noindex, Google will not only not index the page, but also remove the page if it exists, and not archive the page as well.

Using the  indicates that the page was modified. There would be an assumption that the page still exists if you modify this date. But if you are trying to indicate the page is removed, unfortunately sitemaps do not have a mechanism for that. The best you can do is just remove the page from the sitemap. However, that should be a very easy mechanism to create.

Other than that, there is nothing to do but to wait. Google uses a TTL (time to live) style of mechanism to know how often to visit a page or site. If your site is modified often, then the TTL is small meaning that it is likely that Google will find the changes fast and update the index rather fast. You cannot make Google come to Muhammad.

Comment: Good tips! We still have one issue: against our guidelines, many users add information they consider sensitive (phone number, address of the house they sell), etc. After the ad has been deleted, they search that on Google and see the page in Google's index + a cached version (reason why we are thinking about noarchive). Some pages take weeks/months to be removed. Any idea?

Comment: Using noarchive may be a good idea for all the pages as a normal course of business. I agree with that! Otherwise, you cannot get Google to remove the page from the index faster than Google would normally. The only control you have is to update the site pages as often as makes sense thus reducing the TTL (like) value. If you do not want the page indexed, using the noindex will tell Google to remove the page, but that means that Google must respider the page and update the index which takes time. There is no way to tell Google anything. Unfortunately, search engines are not real-time.